# Javascript "confirm" box displaying more than once. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call that is run when a div is clicked. This displays a dynamic drop down menu. Below is the ajax call.

The drop down menu contains a list of other items that can be clicked to launch an "editor". The issue is that when I close the editor I request the user confirm they want to navigate away from the page, based on the answer the div will either close or remain open for further editing. Below is the code that launches the editor:

```
jQuery(function($){


    var launchEditor = "#launch-editor-<?php echo $this->section_num; ?>";
    var contentEditor = jQuery("#<?php echo $this->section_num; ?>-editor");
    var closeEditor = "#<?php echo $this->section_num; ?>-editor-close";
    var closeMessage = "Your changes will not be saved, are you sure you want to close without saving?";

    jQuery(document).on("click", launchEditor, function(){
        contentEditor.unbind();
        contentEditor.show("fade", 1000);
        contentEditor.draggable();
    });

    jQuery(document).on("click", closeEditor, function(){

        if(confirm(closeMessage)){
            contentEditor.fadeOut(1000);
            //contentEditor.die("click");   

        } else {

        }


    });
});
```

The issue is as follows... If I click on the initial div more than once which launches the AJAX call, the "jQuery(document).on("click", closeEditor...)" function bubbles up in the DOM which poses a problem when the user decides to close the editor. Effectively the "confirm" message displays equal to the amount of times the original div is clicked. hope this makes sense... let me know if further info is required... cheers.

Comment: Have you thought of using `once` and rebinding your method when you close the dialog? That way the dialog can only ever be called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following seemed to fix it.. thanks SCRAGAR for your suggestion:

```
closeEditor.one().bind("click", function(){

    if(confirm(closeMessage)){
        contentEditor.fadeOut(1000);
    } else {
        //do something
    }

});
```