# jQuery confirm box should to be clicked more then once

Tags: jquery

I have a form with countdown timer. If the timer has more than 5 minutes and the user wanna submit it, I wanna show a confirm box. But the problem is, the button should to be clicked more than once.

I have used the suggestion like [Javascript "confirm" box displaying more than once. jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912064/javascript-confirm-box-displaying-more-than-once-jquery) for using `.one()` but it doesn't work on me

**jQuery**

```
if(duration>=300){
  $("#submit").one().on("click", function(){
    if(confirm("5 minutes remaining. Are you sure want to submit it?")){
      console.log(true); // for counting how many times the button has been clicked
      return true;
    }
    else {
      console.log(false);
      return false;
    }
   })
}
```

I tried to analyze it and got that the button should to be clicked as much as the duration has running. Is my hypothesis true? Any solution?

Comment: Just a suggestion. You can use bootstrap modal for better customization instead of modifying the behavior of a confirm box. But if you still prefer the confirm box, please update your code to include the HTML script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've found the solution. Those codes actually are in a function. So, i put it out from the function and modified the codes so the confirm box will not depend on the timer function :)